# Sort an array, placing children beneath parents

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parent

So I have an array of items in php, some may be linked to others via a parent_id key. I'm looking to sort this array so that any items whose parent is in this array ends up positioned right below the parent.

**example: (actual array has many more keys)**

```
some_array[0]['id'] = 15001;
some_array[0]['parent_id'] = 14899;

some_array[1]['id'] = 14723;
some_array[1]['parent_id'] = 0; //parent_id of 0 means item has no parent of its own

some_array[2]['id'] = 14899;
some_array[2]['parent_id'] = 0;

some_array[3]['id'] = 15000;
some_array[3][parent_id'] = 14723;
```

**I'd like to sort these so they end up in this order:**

```
some_array[0]['id'] = 14723;

some_array[1]['id'] = 15000;

some_array[2]['id'] = 14899;

some_array[3]['id'] = 15001;
```

ie. items are just below their parents.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you want a version of a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort)

Answer (score 6):

My shorter version of mattwang's answer:

```
/**
 * sort parents before children
 *
 * @param array   $objects input objects with attributes 'id' and 'parent'
 * @param array   $result  (optional, reference) internal
 * @param integer $parent  (optional) internal
 * @param integer $depth   (optional) internal
 * @return array           output
 */
function parent_sort(array $objects, array &$result=array(), $parent=0, $depth=0) {
    foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
        if ($object->parent == $parent) {
            $object->depth = $depth;
            array_push($result, $object);
            unset($objects[$key]);
            parent_sort($objects, $result, $object->id, $depth + 1);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Only actual difference is that it sorts an array of objects instead of an array of arrays.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that you guys are still looking for a real answer to this, but it might help out others with the same problem. Below is a recursive function to resort an array placing children beneath parents.

```
$initial = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'People',
        'ID' => 2,
        'parent' => 0
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Paul',
        'ID' => 4,
        'parent' => 2
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Liz',
        'ID' => 5,
        'parent' => 2
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Comus',
        'ID' => 6,
        'parent' => 3
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Mai',
        'ID' => 7,
        'parent' => 2
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Titus',
        'ID' => 8,
        'parent' => 3
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Adult',
        'ID' => 9,
        'parent' => 6
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Puppy',
        'ID' => 10,
        'parent' => 8
        ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Programmers',
        'ID' => 11,
        'parent' => 4
        )   ,
    array(
        'name' => 'Animals',
        'ID' => 3,
        'parent' => 0
        )                           
    );


/*---------------------------------
function parentChildSort_r
$idField        = The item's ID identifier (required)
$parentField    = The item's parent identifier (required)
$els            = The array (required)
$parentID       = The parent ID for which to sort (internal)
$result     = The result set (internal)
$depth          = The depth (internal)
----------------------------------*/

function parentChildSort_r($idField, $parentField, $els, $parentID = 0, &$result = array(), &$depth = 0){
    foreach ($els as $key => $value):
        if ($value[$parentField] == $parentID){
            $value['depth'] = $depth;
            array_push($result, $value);
            unset($els[$key]);
            $oldParent = $parentID; 
            $parentID = $value[$idField];
            $depth++;
            parentChildSort_r($idField,$parentField, $els, $parentID, $result, $depth);
            $parentID = $oldParent;
            $depth--;
        }
    endforeach;
    return $result;
}

$result = parentChildSort_r('ID','parent',$initial);

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

It's a wind down method that removes elements from the original array and places them into result set in the proper order.  I made it somewhat generic for you, so it just needs you to tell it what your 'ID' field and 'parent' fields are called.  Top level items are required to have a parent_id (however you name it) of 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `usort` to sort by a user defined function:

```php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  if ( $a['id'] == $b['id'] ) {
    return 0;

  } else if ( $a['parent_id'] ) {
    if ( $a['parent_id'] == $b['parent_id'] ) {
       return ( $a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1 );
    } else {
      return ( $a['parent_id'] >= $b['id'] ? 1 : -1 );
    }
  } else if ( $b['parent_id'] ) {
    return ( $b['parent_id'] >= $a['id'] ? -1 : 1);
  } else {
    return ( $a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1 );
  }
}

usort($some_array, "cmp");
```

Note: this will only work with a tree that is one level deep (meaning no children of children). For more complex trees you probably want to sort the data into a graph and then flatten it.

***Edit:*** fixed to edit a case where `$b` has a parent but `$a` does not.

Comment: Yes, I think the most optimal solution for multiple levels is to a) sort by id, b) create the tree, c) flatten. By using references, you can create the tree in O(n) time with a single `foreach` iteration, and if you pre-sort, everything will be in order.

Comment: @Andrew I think you have failed with providing correct answer, but you tried. Consider the following: `array(array('id' => 2,'parent_id' => 0), array('id' => 1,'parent_id' => 2))`. Your code would place child before the parent.

Comment: @Taldeck On the other hand if you switch the two items in that array, you are correct. They appear out of order. I will fix that now.

Comment: @Andrew Just look at your code. The array falls to the last `return` statement and orders the elements using `$a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1` statement. Which means, it does not take parents into account. Yes, I have tested it. No, it does not work. Simplifying the issue: if the child has ID lower than its parent, your solution will fail. Do you see that? And what do you mean by "it worked"? It did not throw the exception, but it did not return proper results either.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, this is another issue - the way your code works depends on which of the array elements is passed as `$a`, and which is passed as `$b`. So, basically, in case of your code `$a > $b` does not mean `$b < $a`.

Comment: @Tadeck If the child has an ID lower than the parent and is sorted in such a way that `$a` does not have a parent and `$b` does then yes, you are correct. I just fixed my code to take care of that. However, the array in your first comment will go into the `} else if ( $a['parent_id'] ) {` path not the `} else {` **Note:** the fix for one bug also fixes the other.

Comment: @Andrew You are talking about the case when the first element of the array is passed as `$b`, and the second is passed as `$a`. Then correct, it would be executed that way. But anyway, the result of that function should not be based on the order of elements - similarly as comparing two integers and deciding which is higher: it should not matter which is first and which is second within the expression.

Comment: @Tadeck I fixed the code to address your issue of ordering in the current code. Also, I think I see some of the the confusion here. `usort` starts at index [1] and compairs it to [0] so the first and only comparison is `cmp( $arr[1], $arr[0] )` and not `cmp( $arr[0], $arr[1] )`... maybe your version of PHP is different. Thank you for your help finding bugs in my sort function, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function and compare two different elements of the '*big array*' in a way you need. This becomes then a question about '*how do I really decide which element is before which element?*'.

Comment: `usort` will only work if the depth is only two layers (no grand children). It looks like @Andrew Curioso's answer solves that nicely.

Comment: @konfronce You are incorrect. @Andrew's answer would sort `array(array('id' => 2,'parent_id' => 0), array('id' => 1,'parent_id' => 2))` to the order where the second element (id=1) is before the first element (id=2) even despite the fact the element with id=1 is a child of element with id=2 and should be placed *after* it. @Andrew failed to answer the question that results from my answer.

Comment: @konforce My answer only solves it in so much as I explicitly stated that I won't work with grandchildren and suggested an alternative algorithm :) And yes, @konfronce found a bug in my `cmp` function. It is fixed now.

Comment: @Andrew It is me who found the bug ;)

Comment: @Andrew Oops!! Sorry, how could I forget that ;). Copy and paste error.

Comment: @Andrew No problem, just making sure I am praised for what have I done ;) (lol) I am happy you have written the function that properly (I hope so, I did not test it after update) solves the problem. I was not trying to do that - I only pointed out `usort()` as the solution to use.

Answer (score 0):

The simple usort won't work if you want to support more than one layer of children. There's simply no way to know how two arbitrary elements compare without other information.

I didn't think about it much, so perhaps it doesn't work. But here's a sorting class:

```
class TopSort
{
  private $sorted, $unsorted;
  private $history;

  public function sort(array $unsorted)
  {
    $this->sorted = array();
    $this->unsorted = $unsorted;
    $this->history = array();

    usort($this->unsorted, function($a, $b)
    {
      return $b['id'] - $a['id'];
    });

    foreach ($this->unsorted as $i => $a)
      if ($a['parent_id'] == 0) $this->visit($i);

    return array_reverse($this->sorted);
  }

  private function visit($i)
  {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $this->history))
    {
      $this->history[$i] = true;
      foreach ($this->unsorted as $j => $a)
        if ($a['parent_id'] == $this->unsorted[$i]['id']) $this->visit($j);

      $this->sorted[] = $this->unsorted[$i];
    }
  }
}

$sorter = new TopSort();
$some_array = $sorter->sort($some_array);
```

The idea here is to first sort in reverse by id. Then build up a new array by inserting the deepest elements (those with no children) first. Since we initially sorted the array by reverse id, it should mean the entire thing is upside down. After reversing the array, it should be exactly like you want. (Of course one could unshift items onto the array to avoid the reverse operation, but that might be slower...)

And this is *very* unoptimized as it iterates over the entire array many, many times. With a little rework, it wouldn't need to do that.

Here's an alternative class that is more optimized:

```
class TopSort
{
  private $sorted;

  public function sort(array $nodes)
  {
    $this->sorted = array();

    # sort by id
    usort($nodes, function($a, $b) {
      return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    });

    # build tree
    $p = array(0 => array());
    foreach($nodes as $n)
    {
      $pid = $n['parent_id'];
      $id = $n['id'];

      if (!isset($p[$pid]))
        $p[$pid] = array('child' => array());

      if (isset($p[$id]))
        $child = &$p[$id]['child'];
      else
        $child = array();

          $p[$id] = $n;
      $p[$id]['child'] = &$child;
      unset($child);

      $p[$pid]['child'][] = &$p[$id];    
    }
    $nodes = $p['0']['child'];
    unset($p);

    # flatten array
    foreach ($nodes as $node)
      $this->flatten($node);

    return $this->sorted;
  }

  private function flatten(array $node)
  {
    $children = $node['child'];
    unset($node['child']);
    $this->sorted[] = $node;
    foreach ($children as $node)
      $this->flatten($node);
  }
}

$sorter = new TopSort();
$sorted = $sorter->sort($some_array);
```

It's a three step approach:

1. Sort by id (usort)
2. Build nested array structure.
3. Flatten array in pre-order.

By virtue of presorting by id, each group of children should be sorted correctly.