# Sort array in hierarchical structure for UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of customer objects that each have an ID for themselves, and a parent ID.

Example:

```
[
    Customer(id: 1, parentId: nil),
    Customer(id: 2, parentId: 3),
    Customer(id: 3, parentId: 1),
    Customer(id: 4, parentId: 1)
]
```

My goal is to rearrange them so that all the children are underneath the parents in the array, like this (or something similar):

```
[
    Customer(id: 1, parentId: nil),
    Customer(id: 4, parentId: 1),
    Customer(id: 3, parentId: 1),
    Customer(id: 2, parentId: 3)
]
```

Then, I'll use this to indent the table view cells to show the hierarchical structure of the customers.

I've seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377147/sort-an-array-placing-children-beneath-parents) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661298/sorting-array-for-every-child-coming-after-parent) but I don't know how to apply this to Swift. How can I sort my array?

Comment: You do expect multiple levels of parents, right? In other words, it's not simply a two-level parent-child hierarchy, there could be more layers to it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah, there can be more than 2 layers. I would need to account for this when I indented the cells, but that's the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need both the indentation level and the order, you should plan ahead and prepare the indentation level along with sorting.

You can do it in a relatively simple way by first adding dependents to parents (or building out dependents outside of parents if you have no control of the `Customer` class), and then walking the tree depth-first, and storing the results in a *topological order*.

Here is an example of how this can be done. It uses this `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : CustomStringConvertible {
    public var Dependents = [Customer]()
    public let Id : Int
    public let Parent : Int?
    public init(_ id:Int, _ parent:Int?) {
        Id = id
        Parent = parent
    }
    public var description: String {
        return "Customer Id=\(Id) Parent=\(Parent)"
    }
}
```

Note how each `Customer` has an array of `Dependents`, along with its own ID and an optional ID of its parent.

Before you sort, you need to add dependents to each customer. You can do it with two calls of `forEach`:

```
let cust = [ Customer(2, 3), Customer(3, 1), Customer(1, nil), Customer(4, 1), Customer(5, 3)]
var byId = [Int:Customer]()
// Add each customer to dictionary by ID
cust.forEach { byId[$0.Id] = $0 }
// Go throug customers again, this time adding them to their parents
cust.forEach { c in
    if let parentId = c.Parent {
        byId[parentId]?.Dependents.append(c)
    }
}
```

With `byId` in place, you can prepare the array for results, and start sorting. I will use tuples of `(Customer, Int)` to represent a customer along with its indentation level:

```
var sorted = [(Customer,Int)]()
// Recursive local function for adding dependents to the result
func store(customer:Customer, _ level:Int) {
    sorted.append((customer, level))
    customer.Dependents.forEach { store($0, level+1) }
}
// Call the recursive function for each top-level customer:
for c in cust.filter({ $0.Parent == nil }) {
    store(c, 0)
}
```

That's it - now we can print the results with indentation, like this:

```
for (customer, level) in sorted {
    let indent = String(count:level, repeatedValue:Character(" "))
    print("\(indent) \(customer)")
}
```

Comment: With arrays of lots of customers, how will this hold up in terms of performance?

Comment: @brimstone Assuming that "lots" on a portable device means "a thousand or two", this shouldn't be bad at all. If you go for a million of customers, you are probably doing it on a server with a powerful CPU, so it shouldn't be too bad either. I can see this becoming a problem with a hundred million of customers, because in that case you may want to exploit some parallelism available on multi-core systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this kind of nested hierarchical sorting using recursion, e.g.

```
/* recursive sorting */
func foo(inout remainingCustomers: [Customer], inout _ sortedCustomers: [Customer], _ parentId: Int? = nil) {
    let children = remainingCustomers.filter { $0.parentId == parentId }
    for child in children {
        sortedCustomers.append(child)
        foo(&remainingCustomers, &sortedCustomers, child.id)
    }
    remainingCustomers = remainingCustomers.filter { $0.parentId != parentId }
}
```

Called with your customer array (say `customer`) and an empty array (say `sortedCustomers`), where the latter is the resulting array into which the sorted customers will be appended.

```
/* example setup */
struct Customer {
    let id: Int
    let parentId: Int?
}

var customers : [Customer] = [
    Customer(id: 13, parentId: 2),
    Customer(id: 14, parentId: 5),
    Customer(id: 1, parentId: nil),
    Customer(id: 2, parentId: 3),
    Customer(id: 7, parentId: 2),
    Customer(id: 3, parentId: 1),
    Customer(id: 4, parentId: 14),
    Customer(id: 5, parentId: nil),
    Customer(id: 6, parentId: 1)]

/* example usage */
var sortedCustomers : [Customer] = []
foo(&customers, &sortedCustomers)

sortedCustomers.forEach { print($0) }
/* Customer(id: 1, parentId: nil)
   Customer(id: 3, parentId: Optional(1))
   Customer(id: 2, parentId: Optional(3))
   Customer(id: 13, parentId: Optional(2))
   Customer(id: 7, parentId: Optional(2))
   Customer(id: 6, parentId: Optional(1))
   Customer(id: 5, parentId: nil)
   Customer(id: 14, parentId: Optional(5))
   Customer(id: 4, parentId: Optional(14))  */
```

Note that the above is not very optimized w.r.t. performance (e.g. the double filtering in `foo`) with growth of the size of the `customers` array. As the context of your sorting is an array that is to be displayed to as user, I assume you will not use the above for arrays of huge sizes. If this becomes and issue, [Knuth would advice us](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) to only then start with mature optimization of this algorithm.

---

To ease review of the result, you could include a `depth` property in the recursion, e.g. as below printing the children (while being appended to `sortedCustomers`) with some padding proportional to depth of recursion:

```
/* recursive sorting */
func foo(inout remainingCustomers: [Customer], inout _ sortedCustomers: [Customer], _ parentId: Int? = nil, _ depth: Int = 0) {
    let children = remainingCustomers.filter { $0.parentId == parentId }
    for child in children {
        sortedCustomers.append(child)
        let padding = String(count: 4*depth, repeatedValue: (" " as Character))
        print(padding + "\(child)")
        foo(&remainingCustomers, &sortedCustomers, child.id, depth+1)
    }
    remainingCustomers = remainingCustomers.filter { $0.parentId != parentId }
}

/* example usage */
var sortedCustomers : [Customer] = []
foo(&customers, &sortedCustomers)
/*
Customer(id: 1, parentId: nil)
    Customer(id: 3, parentId: Optional(1))
        Customer(id: 2, parentId: Optional(3))
            Customer(id: 13, parentId: Optional(2))
            Customer(id: 7, parentId: Optional(2))
    Customer(id: 6, parentId: Optional(1))
Customer(id: 5, parentId: nil)
    Customer(id: 14, parentId: Optional(5))
        Customer(id: 4, parentId: Optional(14))     */
```

Comment: @brimstone Happy to help!